# Agent Library at Laravel. What's Wrong?

Tags: php, laravel, class, scope, namespaces

what's up?
I found this problem: I initiate a new project from 0, installing Laravel with composer:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist Blog
```

The following step was to add the Agent library https://github.com/jenssegers/agent.

```
composer require jenssegers/agent
```

This is the first library that I have ever used on Laravel and I'm not sure if I did it correctly. I added the line codes mentioned in the Agent's README.md at the `config/app.php`. After it, I went to `public/index.php` at my project and add the following lines to test it:

```
use Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent;

$agent = new Agent();
```

Infortunally it didn't work and I had received the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\BlogBRU\public\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\BlogBRU\public\index.php on line 7`. The line 7 correspond to `$agent = new Agent();`
I already tried to modify the `use ...` for:

```
use use Jenssegers\Agent\Facades; 
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;
```

But it doesn't work.
I will appreciate it if you could help me. This is taking all my time!

Comment: Why are you trying that on `index.php` ? Try it on a controller and tell me if it is still not working.

Comment: I think you're right! I put it in a controller and no error was shown again. But when I call the function ```isMobile``` of the library, the Intelephense shows me an error of undefined function. Thank you for the suggestion, would you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no idea if I cannot see the error, you will have to update your question with the new code and error. It is possible that was not working on `index.php` because the composer's `autoloading` start's working there if I am not confused, so it depends a lot where you are writing your code (depends on the line before or after).

Comment: I solve it by creating a middleware that defines a const of DEVICE_TYPE every time that I call ```Route::get()```. Thank you